# How to iterate and update a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have had this problem lots over time, if I iterate a list, and modify the list in the process it causes an exception.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>()
                                {
                                    "one",
                                    "two",
                                    "three"
                                };

        foreach (string item in list)
        {
            if (item == "two")
            {
                list.Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

I have come up with my own solutions, but interested to hear your solutions.

Comment: How many elements are you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could use linq in this case:

```
list = list.Where(s => s != "two").ToList();
```

The long way to go about it would be to build a second list of items to remove, and then iterate through that list removing items from the first list. Here is some example code:

Please note, I highly recommend going with the simple Linq solution, and not doing it this way, but if for some reason Linq is not an option for you this should work:

```
List<string> toRemove = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in list)
{
    if (item == "two")
    {
        toRemove.Add(item);
    }
}

foreach(string item in toRemove)
{
    list.Remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you're not supposed to modify elements in a list that you're iterating over.

Also, you could do this more simply with list.Remove("two");

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution involves LINQ.

```
var filtered = list.Where(s => s != "two").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (list.Contains("two"))
    list.Remove("two");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation

```
list.ForEach(l => { if (l == "two")  list.Remove(l); });
```

Comment: I'm about 99% sure that this will have all the same problems as the code in the original question.

Comment: I didn't understand what problem you mentioned?

Comment: Never mind, apparently this works. I didn't think it would. I stand corrected.

Comment: Actually, according to Reflector, this is not meant to work once `BinaryCompatibility.TargetsAtLeast_Desktop_V4_5` becomes `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list.RemoveAll(s => s == "two");
```

Note this does allow extra processing -- the "iterate" in the OP -- before returning `s == "two"`.