# Java analog of iterator to remove objects from collection

Tags: c#

In Java I can iterate collection and remove some objects from it using `Iterator.remove()` method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()

This is very handly and natural. Like you are looking for food in the fridge and throw away food with expired date. How to do the same in c#?

I want to `iterate` and `clean-up` collection in the same loop.

There are several related question, for example [How to iterate and update a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561495/how-to-iterate-and-update-a-list) however I still can not find exact duplicate of this operation in c#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using `List<T>`, there's a handy method to do this ([`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx)), which will remove all elements which match a predicate (expressed as a delegate). For example:

```
List<Person> people = ...;
people.RemoveAll(person => person.Age < 18);
// Just the adults left now...
```

This is simpler than iterating backwards, IMO.

Of course, if you're happy to create a *new* list instead, you can use LINQ:

```
var adults = people.Where(person => person.Age >= 18).ToList();
```

Comment: I want to have explicit `for` or `foreach` loop because I want to do something with each item. During this processing I want to remove outdated items. Your suggestion only removes outdated items but it doesn't allow me to do work on the rest.

Comment: @javapowered: Sure it does.  The predicate is called for every item, its return value controls whether the item is removed.  You can do work inside the predicate, the only thing you can't do is replace the item (but you can make changes to the members of a reference type which will affect the collection).  Since you can't do work on a removed item, requiring you to return in order to cause removal doesn't seem like an issue.

Comment: @javapowered, another example `var list =  new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6}; list.RemoveAll(i => i % 2 == 0);`

Comment: in Jon first example how to calculate `int totalAgeOfAdults = "delete people younger than 18, sum age of all the rest people"`

Comment: @javapowered, `int sum =  list.Where(p => p.Age >= 18).Sum(p => p.Age);`

Comment: @L.B this will not clean-up initial list. is it `N` or `2*N` operation? backward loop is 2 times faster?

Comment: It is **N**, this is **2*N** `sum = list.ToArray().Where(p => { return p.Age < 18 ? !list.Remove(p) : true; }).Sum(p => p.Age);` So, you want to do exacly the same as you do in java. this is c# world. whether you like it or not, you have the change your style accordingly.

Comment: @javapowered: I would probably process everything in the list, *then* call `RemoveAll`. That separation is likely to keep things simpler.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks, this still will be 2*N. I just already processing list and at some point I think "hmm, i don't need this item, this is garbage". However I can't remove it exactly at this point. Not a big deal of course, but I wonder that Java has something c# doesn't :)

Comment: @javapowered: Yes, it will be 2N. Do you have any evidence that that's actually a problem? You *could* do it in one step by making the delegate perform the processing and just return true/false at the end, at which point it will only iterate through once. And yes, Java iterators do indeed have an optional operation that .NET iterators don't... and vice versa (Reset in .NET). Personally I try not to use either of them most of the time...

Comment: @JonSkeet I used 2*N and this will be fine in 99% of cases, thanks. However I think ability to remove items from collection during iteration is cool feature :)

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can use a `for` loop to iterate over a collection and in it remove items - this will work for `IList<T>` collections.

For safety, you should iterate backwards

```
for(int i = coll.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(coll[i] == something)
  {
     coll.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

If you can use LINQ, look at [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) as Jon Skeet suggests. This will allow you to remove all items from the list without iterating, but simply providing a predicate.

```
coll.RemoveAll(i => i == something);
```

Comment: this potentially can cause an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Just use for loop counting backwards

```
List<string> collection = new List<String> { "Hello", "World", "One", "Two", "Three"};
collection.Dump("Original List");
for(int i = collection.Count-1; i>=0; i-- )
{
    if (collection[i] == "One"){
        collection.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
collection.Dump("After deleting");
```

By the way, this is a classic example from [Knuth books](http://www-cs-staff.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html)

Edit: this example works nicely in LINQPad - for demonstrating purposes. Dump() does not work in VS.

Comment: just want to make it obvious that the key here is deleting by index, and working in reverse doesn't disturb the part of the list remaining to be searched.

Comment: this is a solution but not nice. Jave has nice `iterator` for that stuff but in C# I have to manually iterate backward...